Why does my geometry change drastically after merge by distance?


I often import FBX files from CAD software. I just realized that each mesh object imported splits faces up at certain seams. It remains one mesh object but it is comprised of many split faces. When I merge by distance I get unusual results, even though by initial inspection the mesh and edges look the same. Sure the topo is bad, but I do not have time to retopo. One problem with this geometry is that it's impossible to bevel. Is there a better solution?

Seems like it had some custom normal data, which gets destroyed by Merge because new faces have to be created.

CAD isn't a poly modeler the way Blender is so the mesh it exports won't likely have edges with an equal amount vertices that you can just cleanly merge without it messing up the normals. If you want a bevel look to the edge the bevel node in the shader editor might be a solution.

It turns out there is a workflow for dealing with non-manifold meshes from CAD software. First select the mesh and enter edit mode.

Merge by distance
Clear custom normals
Shade flat
Shade auto-smooth (if you want)

This removes the terrible shading errors and has worked for every example mesh I have tried.

You don't show an example file so we can't investigate... My guess is you remove 0 area faces, which have no normals, so now smooth shading has faces with orthogonal normals to interpolate to:

or if all faces are disconnected, even without removing any faces you connect the faces to have neighboring orthogonal faces for smooth shading interpolation...

Remove zero area faces? Is that a command I can execute?

@JamesRiley if no vertex lies on an edge, then "Merge by Distance" does it...

"Remove zero area faces? Is that a command I can execute?" Yes. It's called Degenerate Dissolve. From Edit Mode: Mesh > Cleanup > Degenerate Dissolve.
